# Request new singleton bean "WebDriver" between each @Test scope

Tags: java, spring, selenium, testing, testng

How can I receive a new bean between each `@Test`?

Example:

```
public class Person(){
 private String name = "bob";
 //getters //setters
}

public Class MyTest(){
  @Autowired
  private Person person;

 @Test
 public void firstName(){
   person.setName = "Peter";
   system.out.println(person.getName());
   (Should print out Peter)
 }

 @Test
 public void firstNameTest2(){
   system.out.println(person.getName());
   (Should be reset and print bob)
}
```

I've been using `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.ON_TEST_METHOD)` As a TestClass Annotation, however, this is horrible.. my other frameworks re-init between each test... and slows everything down by a full minute.

I've tried to configure custom scope, and I implemented the Spring Listeners... I reset my Person Bean after each test method... 
However, that only works at the class level, it doesn't give me a new Person object between `@Test` scopes.

Thank you, let me know if you need more code to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the framework you're using. But in any case you need a bean of scope `prototype`, not a `singleton`. A new `prototype` bean is created for each dependency injection:

```
<bean id="obj" class="java.lang.Object" scope="prototype"/>
```

**JUnit and its direvatives**. The feature of JUnit is that it re-creates test class for every test method for isolation purposes. This means its fields are getting re-initialized every time, so you don't need to do anything to get `prototype` bean work - just `@Autowire` that field.

**TestNG**. This framework doesn't re-create test class, so it's a bit more involved to get `prototype` working for each method:

```
@Autowired Object obj;
@Autowired ApplicationContext appContext;

@BeforeMethod
public void injectSpringBeans() {
    obj = appContext.getBean("obj");
}
```

### Why you don't want this

**Test Data can be created with factories**. In your example you create an instance of `Person` which seems like test data. Spring is used to init a graph of cross-dependent beans. If the object doesn't have dependencies and is not shared between multiple other beans it's more natural to create it in the target classes or use Factories.

**Webdriver is shared with Page Objects**. Question title says about `webdriver` though. If you're using Page Objects-like frameworks that also have a link to `webdriver` then you'd be using a different webdriver than the rest of your code. Which simply won't work. Moreover `webdriver` is rarely used in the tests themselves - it's usually hidden by Business Layer or Page Objects layer completely. Read [this article](http://qala.io/blog/evolution-of-automation-test-engineer.html) for details. If you need a new webdriver instance, prepare to re-create a lot of other objects as well.

You can implement your own Spring scope or use something like `thread` scope for all your test-beans and run every method in its own thread (TestNG allows that). But that's going to be complicated and will perform poorly as creating new `webdriver` session means starting a new browser which is very expensive.